# Need to point subdomain to a different dedicated server

Tags: subdomain

Iam trying to point domain to a different dedicated Linux server.

What I've already done:

1. On server1 changed A record to an IP of server2 (*IP which has been already assigned to subdomain*)
2. Created package and account on server2 for sub-domain
3. I am getting error when I visit sub-domain (I have already tried `ipconfig /flushdns`):

> If you feel you have reached this page
>   in error, please contact the web site
>   owner:
>
> webmaster@ads.pixfuture.net It may be
>   possible to restore access to this
>   site by following these instructions
>   for clearing your dns cache. If you
>   are the web site owner, it is possible
>   you have reached this page because:
>
> The IP address has changed. There has
>   been a server misconfiguration. The
>   site may have been moved to a
>   different server. If you are the owner
>   of this website and were not expecting
>   to see this page, please contact your
>   hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what record is being returned with "nslookup <hostname>" in a command window. While flushing your local DNS cache is a good idea, if your configured nameserver(s) still have the old record cached, it will return that until the TTL expires.

Comment: Well. Its interesting because nslookup shows main IP address of the server2. What you saying I did it right?

Comment: By the way FTP access works. I'm lost now. Why then sub-domain shows error?

Comment: In the case that the host is resolving to the correct address, there's likely a mismatch between the configuration of the web server and the host name. In the case of an Apache web server, the vast majority of hosting is based on name-based virtual hosts. This works by inspecting the the request from the browser for a Host header. It uses this to match against a specific configuration statement in the web server which will identify the correct configuration statements to use.

If the configuration does not match the Host header, the web server will serve the request with the default host name.

Comment: @mcmeel/ Its now showing when i type 'www.subdomain.mydomain.com', but without 'www.' still same thing. However, I've made 2 A records on server1 'www.subdomain' and 'subdomain'; I guess its just matter of time as you said. Lets see whats gonna happen. Ill write back here as soon as I get this thing to work

Comment: If you've verified that both the www.subdomain.mydomain.com and the subdomain.mydomain.com hosts are correctly resolving to the correct IP address, I suspect the web server is configured to recognize the www'ized host name, but does not recognize the non-www address. In the Apache world, the ServerAlias allows configuration of a second host name for a virtual server statement. It sounds like you're using a hosting solution that abstracts all the web server configuration, so I apologize that the Apache references may not be entirely helpful.

Comment: Its back again i dont get it. Its still showing that error. Here is my question now: should I set ns1.sever1.com and ns2.server1.com or whould i point to ns1.server2.com and ns2.server2.com records?

Comment: It's difficult to answer that question without additional details about the environment. The nuts and bolts of the problem is that you will need DNS servers to resolve host names into addresses, and the servers at those addresses will need to be configured to serve up content based on those host names. If you're changing providers while moving to the new server, it may very well be necessary to update the authoritative DNS as you've described. If these are hosts you own/control, you should have some flexibility as to how you proceed.

Comment: Ok. Now I got this thing to work. Everything was set up correctly. I checked at the europe's location and it was perfect than I made ping in different countries and screenshots of the website. Its just still propagating at this place here. I guess I have to wait couple hours until it starts working here. thanks a lot for your help learned many new things. chrs!